# Adding role to newly joined user not working Discord.js 14

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to add a role to a newly joined member into my discord server using my discord bot created with discord.js 14. It doesn't seem to work though. Here is my code:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async guildMember => {
    var i = "role id";
    let role = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === i);
    await guildMember.roles.add(role);
})
```

I've tried joining from my alt account but it doesn't work. All intents are enabled. Help is appreciated :)

Comment: What intents are enabled?

Comment: All intents are enabled

Comment: Could you edit your question and add that part of your code where you instantiate the `client`?

Comment: try fetching the role instead of getting it from cache because maybe you haven't fetched it before